# How to enable Auto Hot Reload in Android Studio for Flutter project?

Tags: android-studio, flutter

Instead of pressing "Ctrl + S" or 'hot load' button every time, is there any way to perform auto hot reload whenever code changes in android studio?

Comment: I could explain how you could add an easier shortcut. Are you interested in that?

Comment: Sure. But auto reload would be better. I saw this is possible in VS code.

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned in a comment, this is not quite auto hot reload, but only easier access.
In `File -> Settings`, you can select the `Keymap`. In there, you either search for *`Flutter Hot Reload`*:

[image]

Or you can manually navigate to any of `Main menu -> Run` or `Plug-ins -> Flutter`.

Now, you can double-click or press the secondary mouse button to either add a **keyboard** or **mouse** shortcut. To have something that triggers all the time, you could e.g. add something like <kbd>Enter</kbd> (via the `+`) or the scroll wheel.

If you want to disable hot reload on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, you can go to `Languages & Frameworks -> Flutter` in the settings or search for *`Perform hot reload on save`*.

Answer (score 0):

I think `Auto reload` is currently only available in **VS Code**. **Android Studio** did not implement it. `Auto Reload` has many problems, for example, it reloads even if another file has got an errors and also makes the IDE slow.